# How to capture all http requests of apache by mod_wsgi?

Tags: php, python, apache, xss, mod-wsgi

I need to capture all request of apache web server with mod_wsgi. Checking attacks of GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use mod_wsgi to capture any request to Apache. All you could do it use a WSGI middleware to capture details for requests going into a specific WSGI application. See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Tracking_Request_and_Response

BTW, your requirement is vague as to what exactly you want to catch. You should also look for other purpose built Apache modules. A module supporting use of a specific language isn't going to help you.